# How to wait until request.get finish then conduct the next block in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, request

I am new to NodeJS and I am working on a `request.get` problem. My goal is simply have a function that request the web, and when request finished, the function returns the result, otherwise it returns an error message.

Here's the function that I used for request:

```
var artistNameIdMap = {};
var getPopularArtists = async () => {
    //https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback
    var options = {
        url: CONSTANTS.API_ENDPOINTS.playlist_endpoint + subpath,
        headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token,
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        json: true
    }
    
    request.get(options, function(error, response, body) {
        if (response.statusCode === 200){
            console.log("inside");
            artistNameIdMap = getArtistNameIdMap(body, artistNameIdMap);
        } else {
            res.send("get popular error");
            return {};
        }
    })

    console.log("outside");
    return artistNameIdMap;


module.exports = {
    GetPopularArtists: getPopularArtists
}
```

And this function is included in a `getPopular.js` file. I would like to call the function in another file `playlist.js`.

In `playlist.js`, I wrote

```
const getPopular = require('./controllers/getPopular');
router.get("/BPM/:BPM", (req, res) =>{
    const artistNameIdMap = getPopular.GetPopularArtists();
    console.log(artistNameIdMap);
    let BPM = req.params.BPM;
    res.send(BPM);
})
```

However the result I got is

```
outside
Promise { {} }
inside
```

It seems like the return was before the request gives back the information. I wonder what should I write to make sure that I can obtain the correct `artistNameIdMap` at `playlist.js`.

Comment: for a start, `getPopularArtists` returns a Promise, since it is `async` ... and second, the promise is returned *resolved* without waiting for the `request.get` callback ... making a function `async` does not magically make it wait for asynchronous code to finish, and somehow extract the value returned inside a callback - async/await is used to handle promises, exclusively

Comment: @Bravo Thanks for replying! I removed `async` and now I got `outside {} inside`. How should I revise the code to get the `request.get` callback?

Comment: FYI, the `request` library has been deprecated and it is not recommended that you use it for new code.  You can see a [list of alternatives](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143) here.  My favorite from that list is `got()` and all the options in that list support promises natively which is the preferred way to code asynchronous operations now in nodejs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though you've already accepted an answer, there are a couple of additional things I can add.  First, the `request()` library has been [deprecated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) and it is not recommended for new code.  Second, there is a list of recommended alternatives [here](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143).  Third, all these alternatives support promises natively as that is the preferred way to program asynchronous code in modern nodejs programming.

My favorite alternative is [got()](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) because I find it's interface simple and clean to use and it has the features I need.  Here's how much simpler your code would be using `got()`:

```
const got = require('got');
let artistNameIdMap = {};

async function getPopularArtists() {
    const options = {
        headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token,
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    };
    const url = CONSTANTS.API_ENDPOINTS.playlist_endpoint + subpath;
    let results = await got(url, options).json();
    // update local cache object
    artistNameIdMap = getArtistNameIdMap(results, artistNameIdMap);
    return artistNameIdMap;
}

module.exports = {
    GetPopularArtists: getPopularArtists
}
```

Note: The caller should supply error handling based on the returned promise.

```
GetPopularArtists().then(results => {
    console.log(results);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks so much! The logic is much clear without a nested `(error, response, body) => {...}` function inside of the `request.get()`. But to handle the error for `await got(url, options).json();`, should I directly do `if/else` judgement on attributes or methods of `results`?

Comment: @IsaKyodo - It does not seem to me like it makes sense to handle the error inside this function.  You're not handling the success inside this function and usually you should send an error response and a success response at the same calling level.  If you wanted to handle an error locally, you would surround the `await` with a `try/catch`.  As the code is written here, an error will cause the returned promise to be rejected which is where you should be catching it so you handle success and error at the same level.

Comment: @IsaKyodo - You can certainly do `if` on `results` if you need to, but errors from `got()` such as a non-2xx return status will be thrown automatically as rejected promises (one more thing that `got()` does for you automatically).

Comment: So if I would like to handle the error in caller, should I write in caller (`playlists.js`) : 

`router.get("/BPM/:BPM", async (req, res) =>{ 
const result = await getPopular.GetPopularArtists();  
if (result ... ) // error handling
 }`

Comment: I would appreciate so much if you could kindly enlighten me more specifically how to call the `getPopular.GetPopularArtists()` and how to handle the error in caller. Thanks so much!!

Comment: @IsaKyodo - I added an error handling example to my answer a little while ago.  Is that what you needed?

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to use Promises, use it like this

```
const getPopularArtists = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) {
    const options = {
        url: CONSTANTS.API_ENDPOINTS.playlist_endpoint + subpath,
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token,
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        json: true
    }

    request.get(options, (error, response, body) => {
        if (error) {
            reject(error);
        } else if (response.statusCode === 200) {
            console.log("inside");
            resolve(getArtistNameIdMap(body, artistNameIdMap));
        } else {
            reject("get popular error");
        }
    });
});

module.exports = {
    GetPopularArtists: getPopularArtists
}
```

And use it like

```
const getPopular = require('./controllers/getPopular');
router.get("/BPM/:BPM", async (req, res) =>{
    try {
        const artistNameIdMap = await getPopular.GetPopularArtists();
        console.log(artistNameIdMap);
        let BPM = req.params.BPM;
        res.send(BPM);
    } catch(err) {
        res.send(err);
    }
})
```

---

Alternatively, without promises, you'll need to use a `callback`

Using callbacks:

```
const getPopularArtists = (callback) => {
    const options = {
        url: CONSTANTS.API_ENDPOINTS.playlist_endpoint + subpath,
        headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token,
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        json: true
    }
    
    request.get(options, function(error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
            callback(error);
        } else if (response.statusCode === 200){
            console.log("inside");
            callback(null, getArtistNameIdMap(body, artistNameIdMap));
        } else {
            callback("get popular error");
        }
    })
};

module.exports = {
    GetPopularArtists: getPopularArtists
}
```

And use it like:

```
const getPopular = require('./controllers/getPopular');
router.get("/BPM/:BPM", (req, res) =>{
    getPopular.GetPopularArtists((err, artistNameIdMap) => {
        if (err) {
            // handle error here
        } else {
            console.log(artistNameIdMap);
            let BPM = req.params.BPM;
            res.send(BPM);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I've added a non-promise version @IsaKyodo - in case  you want to see what that would look like - I also changed the logic a little for the case where `response.statusCode === 200` is false